# jQuery keyup update file on server

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have code similar to the code below:

```
<?php
...
$file3 = fopen('.../rate.txt','r');
$rate_a = array(100);
for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++)
{
   $rate_a[$i]=fgets($file3);
}
fclose($file3);
for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++)
{
$x = $x.'
<select id="rate'.$i.'_" name="'.$rate.'">
<option value="'.$rate_a[$i].'" selected="selected">'.$rate_a[$i].'</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br>';
}
?>

<html>
<form action="sendreplayadmin" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php echo $x; ?>

</form>
</html>
```

Everything works, my HTML code is generated fine with the selected values from every line in rate.txt. Now when someone selects another value I want to auto update the txt file. I can get the value with jQuery's keyup function but I don`t know how to edit the txt file. Do I have to execute the php code somehow in jQuery? Or not? I have no idea.

Comment: You have to do it on server side, and as you rightly said using php and jquery. Send a request through `AJAX` using `$.post`, `$.get` or `$.ajax` to send necessary information to another php page where you will process the data and update the file

Comment: JavaScript cannot write files to your file system. Just the same, JavaScript cannot execute `PHP` code. You're going to have to make an `Ajax` call server side in order to execute the `PHP` to update the file.

Comment: any example or links, I didn`t use ajax :\